# populate data in amchart django

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PRODUCTS, null = True)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True)
```

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    context = {
        'orders': orders,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

Here I have multiple orders for samsung, apple etc. There should be only one data for samsung, apple and so on. How can I aggregate order_quantity for each product and send data as the format required for the data?

I need the following data format to show data in amchart bar diagram. How can I achieve it?

Format required for graph

```
var data = [
              {
                name: "Samsung",
                value: 35654,
              },
              {
                name: "Apple",
                value: 65456,
              },
              {
                name: "Xiomi",
                value: 45724,
              },
            ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do:

```
Order.objects.annotate(total_items_sold=Sum("order_set__order_quantity").values("name", "items_sold")
```

Which you then convert to a list of dictionaries? I.e. the data format you require.